# Correct use of memcpy

Tags: c++, arrays, memcpy

I have some problems with a project I'm doing.
 Basically I'm just using memcpy the wrong way. I know the theroy of pointer/arrays/references and should know how to do that, nevertheless I've spend two days now without any progress. 
 I'll try to give a short code overview and maybe someone sees a fault! I would be very thankful.

The Setup: I'm using an ATSAM3x Microcontroller together with a uC for signal aquisition. I receive the data over SPI. 
I have an Interrupt receiving the data whenever the uC has data available. The data is then stored in a buffer (int32_t buffer[1024 or 2048]). There is a counter that counts from 0 to the buffer size-1 and determines the place where the data point is stored. Currently I receive a test signal that is internally generated by the uC

```
//ch1: receive 24 bit data in 8 bit chunks -> store in an int32_t
ch1=ch1|(SPI.transfer(PIN_CS, 0x00, SPI_CONTINUE)<<24)>>8; 
ch1=ch1|(SPI.transfer(PIN_CS, 0x00, SPI_CONTINUE)<<16)>>8;
ch1=ch1|(SPI.transfer(PIN_CS, 0x00, SPI_CONTINUE)<<8)>>8;

if(Not Important){
_ch1Buffer[_ch1SampleCount] = ch1;   
_ch1SampleCount++;
if(_ch1SampleCount>SAMPLE_BUFFER_SIZE-1) _ch1SampleCount=0;
}
```

This ISR is active all the time. Since I need raw data for signal processing and the buffer is changed by the ISR whenever a new data point is available, i want to copy parts of the buffer into a temporary "storage".

To do so, I have another, global counter wich is incremented within the ISR. In the mainloop, whenever the counter reaches a certain size, i call a method get some of the buffer data (about 30 samples).
The method aquires the current position in the buffer:

```
'int ch1Pos = _ch1SampleCount;'
```

and then, depending on that position I try to use memcpy to get my samples. Depending on the position in the buffer, there has to be a "wrap-around" to get the full set of samples:

```
    if(ch1Pos>=(RAW_BLOCK_SIZE-1)){
        memcpy(&ch1[0],&_ch1Buffer[ch1Pos-(RAW_BLOCK_SIZE-1)] , RAW_BLOCK_SIZE*sizeof(int32_t));        
    }else{
        memcpy(&ch1[RAW_BLOCK_SIZE-1 - ch1Pos],&_ch1Buffer[0],(ch1Pos)*sizeof(int32_t));
        memcpy(&ch1[0],&_ch1Buffer[SAMPLE_BUFFER_SIZE-1-(RAW_BLOCK_SIZE-  ch1Pos)],(RAW_BLOCK_SIZE-ch1Pos)*sizeof(int32_t));          
    }
```

- _ch1Buffer is the buffer containing the raw data

  - SAMPLE_BUFFER_SIZE is the size of that buffer
- ch1 is the array wich is supposed to hold the set of samples

  - RAW_BLOCK_SIZE is the size of that array
- ch1Pos is the position of the last data point written to the buffer from the ISR at the time where this method is called

Technically I'm aware of the requirements, but apparently thats not enough ;-).
I know, that the data received by the SPI interface is "correct". The problem is, that this is not the case for the extracted samples. There are a lot of spikes in the data that indicate that I've been reading something I wasn't supposed to read.
 I've changed the memcpy commands that often, that I completly lost the overview. The code sample above is one version of many's, and while you're reading this I'm sure I've changed everything again.

I would appreciate every hint!
Thanks & Greetings!

**EDIT**
I've written down everything (again) on a sheet of paper and tested some constellations. This is the updated Code for the memcpy part:

```
        if(ch1Pos>=(RAW_BLOCK_SIZE-1)){
        memcpy(&ch1[0],&_ch1Buffer[ch1Pos-(RAW_BLOCK_SIZE-1)] , RAW_BLOCK_SIZE*sizeof(int32_t));
    }else{
        memcpy(&ch1[RAW_BLOCK_SIZE-1-ch1Pos],&_ch1Buffer[0],(ch1Pos+1)*sizeof(int32_t));
        memcpy(&ch1[0],&_ch1Buffer[SAMPLE_BUFFER_SIZE-(RAW_BLOCK_SIZE-1-ch1Pos)],(RAW_BLOCK_SIZE-1-ch1Pos)*sizeof(int32_t));
    }
}
```

This already made it a lot better. From all the changes, everything kinda got messed up. Now there is just one Error there.
 There is a periodical spike. I'll try to get more information, but I think it is a wrong access while wrapping around.
I've changed the `if(_ch1SampleCount>SAMPLE_BUFFER_SIZE-1) _ch1SampleCount=0;` to `if(_ch1SampleCount>=SAMPLE_BUFFER_SIZE) _ch1SampleCount=0;`.

**EDIT II**
To answer the Questions of @David Schwartz :

- SPI.transfer returns a single byte
- The buffer is initialised once at startup: `memset(_ch1Buffer,0,sizeof(int32_t)*SAMPLE_BUFFER_SIZE);`

**EDIT III**
Sorry for the frequent updates, the comment section is getting too big.
I managed to get rid of a bunch of zero values at the beginning of the stream by decreasing ch1Pos: 'int ch1Pos = _ch1SampleCount;' 
 Now there is just one periodic "spike" (wrong value). It must be something with the splitted memcpy command. I'll continue looking. If anyone has an idea ... :-)

Comment: `if(ch1Pos>=(RAW_BLOCK_SIZE-1))` looks suspicious I would expect `RAW_BLOCK_SIZE` as the detected wrap-round point.

Comment: Hey! Since  `_ch1SampleCount` goes from 0 to `RAW_BLOCK_SIZE-1` I thought it should be that. But I'll try it right away :-)

Comment: @Galik: The condition is actually `> RAW_BLOCK_SIZE-1` which is `>= RAW_BLOCK_SIZE`.. And since it's only incremented by one, we might as well write `== RAW_BLOCK_SIZE`

Comment: Looks like you're trying to duplicate boost::cyclic_buffer.

Comment: `int ch1Pos = _ch1SampleCount;`  suggests to me that `ch1Pos` can be equal to the size of the array which is `RAW_BLOCK_SIZE`. So the equality test should include that position, not one less.

Comment: Ok, its still jibberish comming out, but I think from all the editing at multiples parts of the code i pretty much messed everythin up...

Comment: And indeed the wrap-round math too should probably use `RAW_BLOCK_SIZE` not one less.

Comment: @Galik `_ch1SampleCount` adresses the buffer via the [] operator and therefore goes from 0 to `RAW_BLOCK_SIZE-1`

Comment: @MSalters Hey! Do you have any experience with that library? I have to do that code as a library for the arduino due as a library (educational uses). Since it should run as fast as possible due to the sampling rates...

Comment: @Chuchaki Yes but you don't want to wrap round until you move out of the bounds by 1

Comment: True. Currently I'm redoing all on a sheet of papre :-) I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: What type does `SPI.transfer` return? Does `ch1` get zeroed before those three ORs?

Comment: I was asking if `ch1` was zeroed, not the buffer. I see three ORs to `ch1` but no zero. Also, are you sure `int` is wide enough on your platform for code like `SPI.transfer(PIN_CS, 0x00, SPI_CONTINUE)<<24` to do the right thing? (I guess you'd probably get a compiler error if not.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Hey, sry I misread the question. Everytime the interrupt routine starts the data reading, ch1 is initialised : `int32_t ch1 = 0;` The Processor I use can handle 32 bits. I receive signed 24 bits & with the shifting I put those 24bits into the integer without loosing the sign information.